# Create sequence of dates in format yyyymmddHHMM with 12 hour increment in bash

Tags: bash, loops, command-line

**Tl;dr**: Is there a nice way of creating a sequence of dates with 12 hour increment in the format yyyymmddHHMM in the bash?

Consider I have a python-script which accepts a certain time (yyyymmddHHMM) as input -t, i could run it like this for instance

```
python myscript.py -t 201411140000
```

which the then starts `myscript.py`for the date 2014-11-14 00:00. Now I want to run the script for many dates, beginning from 2014-01-01 00:00 to 2014-11-14 00:00 with an increment of 12 hours, i.e. i want to produce all the following lines:

```
python myscript.py -t 201401010000
python myscript.py -t 201401011200
python myscript.py -t 201401020000
.
.
.
python myscript.py -t 201411131200
python myscript.py -t 201411140000
```

The closest to what I came is (echo to verify results without running them):

```
for mm in {01..10}; do for dd in {01..31}; do for HH in 00 12; do echo python myscript.py -t 2014$mm$dd$HH\00; done; done; done
```

It produces all required dates from Jan to Oct, but also some **absurd dates**, such as **201402310000**, which the program then has to handle (i.e. throw/log errors). That is not a huge issue, but it feels dirty.
In the end, another loop is required to handle the missing dates Nov-01 to Nov-14, which, again, seems dirty to me.

How can I create those dates more nicely - or is the way above the appropriate way of doing so?

Comment: Use the [`date` (manpage)](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html) command with `-d` option. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the start date to a UNIX timestamp, and iterate over the range in 43200-second (12-hour) increments.

```
for ((ts=$(date +%s --date "2014-11-01 0000");
      ts <= $(date +%s --date "2014-11-14 0000");
      ts+=12*3600)); do
    python myscript.py -t $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M --date @$ts)
done
```

Comment: Thank you, as far as i can see, this code exactly produces the desired results!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `-d` option:

```
$>for i in $(seq 0 12 72); do
  date -d "+$i hours"  +%Y%m%d%H%M;
done

201411141544
201411150344
201411151544
201411160344
201411161544
201411170344
201411171544
```

And if you want a starting date (thanks to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932496/create-sequence-of-dates-in-format-yyyymmddhhmm-with-12-hour-increment-in-bash#comment42410175_26932652)):

```
$> for i in $(seq 0 12 72); do  
   date -d "2014-11-01 0000 +$i hours"  +%Y%m%d%H%M;
done

201411010000
201411011200
201411020000
201411021200
201411030000
201411031200
201411040000
```

Comment: You'll want to put the starting time in the argument to `-d` as well (`-d "2014-11-01 0000 +12 hours"`, for example).

Comment: That should work, therefore you deserve the upvote. It looks cleaner/easier to understand than the solution by @chepner , but his solution fits better, as also the "python myscript.py -t "-part is added. Hence I'll accept chepners answer, but still thank you! I will probably form my own solution from both answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Numeric addition to processed dates is bad practice - there are many edge cases and gotchas. It's just a bad plan.

Fortunately, most computers don't do that. Unix systems use 'epoch' time, which is a count of seconds since 1970.

So you can numerically add 12 hours in seconds (12 * 60 * 60).

In perl, I'd do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $t = localtime();

my $num = 300;

for ( 1 ..  $num ) {
    $t += 12 * 60 * 60;
    print $t -> strftime ( "%y%m%d%H%M" ), "\n";
}
```

That'll do 12 hour cycles starting from right now. Shifting to midnight is left as an exercise for the reader :).

Comment: I was not doing numeric additions with dates, i was concatenating strings (at least i was thinking that i was doing so)